# This code doesnt work. trying to use a loop to get the sizes of my images the first one comes but the others dont

Tags: javascript

```
$j(document).ready(<script type="text/JavaScript">
  function getProps(){
    var imgwidth = [];
    var imgheight = [];
    var w, h;
    var width = document.getElementById('des').clientWidth;
    var height = document.getElementById('des').clientHeight;

    img = document.getElementById('des').getElementsByTagName('img').length;

    w = document.getElementById('des').getElementsByTagName('img');
    h = document.getElementById('des').getElementsByTagName('img');

    for ( count = 0; count < img; count++){

      imgwidth[count] = w.item(count).clientWidth;
      imgheight[count] = h.item(count).clientHeight;

    }
</script>);
```

Comment: you should post the relevant HTML to supplement this javascript.

Comment: I'm pretty sure those `<script>` tags should not be in your JavaScript code `:P`

Comment: Why do you have a `<script>` tag _inside_ `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: i guess you have no questopm

Comment: $j is jquery ? why not use `$j('#des img').each(function(){})` ?

Comment: sory dats an error from me would ask d question again

Comment: @AlexDavies what you mean ? you duplicated question or what ?

Comment: nope check the answer to the question below its the correct way of writing it but it still doesn't work when i try to display the sizes. the first iteration works but the rest gives me zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want, I refactored your code a little:

```
function getProps()
{
    var imgwidth = [];
    var imgheight = [];

    var images = document.getElementById('des').getElementsByTagName('img');
    var count = images.length;

    for ( i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {

        imgwidth[i] = images[i].clientWidth;

        imgheight[i] = images[i].clientHeight;

    }

    console.log(imgwidth);
    console.log(imgheight);
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    getProps()
});​
```

I have set up a jsfiddle for you to demonstrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/JbpdW/

**Edit**

If you use jQuery (what you obvilously do), you can simplify that process a little by using:

```
$("#des img").each(function(i)
{
    imgwidth[i] = this.clientWidth;
    imgheight[i] = this.clientHeight;
});
```

Comment: Tnks a million would try dis baby

Answer (score 0):

with jquery it is very short:

```
$j(function() {

  var result=$j.map($('#des img'),function(el,i) {
    var $el=$j(el); //optimize 
    return {width:$el.width(),height:$el.height()};
  });
  console.log(result);

});
```

please note that i used array of objects instead of two variables, it easer to work with one variable than with two :)
http://jsbin.com/uzikeh/2/edit